# Restore sharepoint 2007 website on a different sharepoint 2007 server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I'd like to update existing production moss2007 website and to do that I want to create this website on my dev environmen (vhd win 2003EE, MOSS 2007 trial version).

I was given:

1. some stp files which include(aspx pages, javascript files, etc...)
2. some aspx pages, masterpage, css file
3. some wsp files
4. source code for almost all wsp files.

There is no documentation how to install all this stuff and I'm not a sharepoint developer but Asp.net dev in fact.

I set up local dev enviroment (i had no problems when following http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28
) and try to create a website based on given files.

My questions:

1. Do I need a copy of the database?
2. I noticed that one of wsp files is not a webpart but a project that contains some web controls  and even a master page) - what should I do with it?
3. I tried to import all stp files. I had to use stsadm, but I can't see them. I can list them using "stsadm -o enumtemplates" - all of them have the same id!
   I changed stp->cab->modified the "WebUrl" in the manifest.xml -> created new cab and rename it to stp-> imported to sharepoint but still the same, I can't see them (custom tab is still not visible).
   I created a custom site template locally (custom tab appeared with it) and opened its manifest.xml. I noticed that the section  contains 17 parameters (manifest.xml files from other stp files 9 parameters only).
   I think that my SharePoint (Trial version) works in a different way and that's the problem.
   Can it be?
4. What is the best way to create this site locally?

thx ahead for all answers

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set up development environment containing the same functionality as your production server, you can duplicate your production site collection by:

1. Copying and attaching production SharePoint content database to your development environment farm
2. Backuping and restoring it by stsadm tool

By firstly you need to prepare your development environment. If you have any wsp solutions deployed on production farm, deploy it on your development environment.
Then if you prefer first option check [this link](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-12-Backup-Restore_a_site_collection_in_SharePoint_2007.aspx)
If you prefer second option check [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/WorldofTray/archive/2010/02/23/how-to-connect-to-a-restored-content-database-in-sharepoint.aspx)

But if you prefer backup way, you can catch some problems with version difference between production and development revilement, different updates installed, so different assemblies in GAC.
So I advice to use attach database way, it should upgrade attached database if it has different version automatically. 
Just google little bit, may be you'll find more complete guide for attaching or restoring site collections. I just give you start point.